# Ellipsis render for Datables

Tags: javascript, json, datatables

I'm working on a CI project that requires the use of datatables, some of the content in the database has a large number of characters and i want to limit those to 150, i have tried to use the examples that are posted in the datatables site without luck, just to be clear i didn´t made this full script, I took it from somewhere else.

This is my script

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

   var st = $('#search_type').val();
    var table = $('#consulta-table').DataTable({
        "dom" : "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
                "<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>",
      "processing": false,

        "pagingType" : "full_numbers",
        "pageLength" : 15,
        "serverSide": true,
        "orderMulti": false,
        "order": [
        <?php if($default_order != null) : ?>
          [<?php echo $default_order ?>, "<?php echo $default_order_type ?>"]
        <?php else : ?>
            [6, "desc"]
        <?php endif; ?>
        ],
        "columns": [
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        { "orderable": false },
        { "orderable": false },
        null,
        { "orderable": false }
    ],
        "ajax": {
            url : "<?php echo site_url("consultas/consultas_page/" . $page . "/" . $catid) ?>",
            type : 'GET',
            data : function ( d ) {
                d.search_type = $('#search_type').val();
            }
        },
        "drawCallback": function(settings, json) {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
      }
    });
    $('#form-search-input').on('keyup change', function () {
    table.search(this.value).draw();
});

} );
function change_search(search) 
    {
      var options = [
        "search-like", 
        "search-exact",
        "title-exact",
        "title2-exact",
        "title3-exact",
        "title4-exact",
        "title5-exact",
        "title6-exact",
      ];
      set_search_icon(options[search], options);
        $('#search_type').val(search);
        $( "#form-search-input" ).trigger( "change" );
    }

function set_search_icon(icon, options) 
    {
      for(var i = 0; i<options.length;i++) {
        if(options[i] == icon) {
          $('#' + icon).fadeIn(10);
        } else {
          $('#' + options[i]).fadeOut(10);
        }
      }
    }
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't this a question of adding style? Something like this perhaps> `<td style="max-width: 307px; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; display: block;">`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [this](https://datatables.net/blog/2016-02-26) yet? It is the official plugin offered by people under the [datatables.net](https://datatables.net/) community. You just need to follow the instruction there and you're good to go.

Simply download/copy the plugin script then, follow this sample code

```
$('#myTable').DataTable( {
columnDefs: [ {
    targets: 0,
    render: $.fn.dataTable.render.ellipsis()
} ]} );
```

Comment: i tried that, the data won't load after use that